# sikuli how to check multiple images at the same time

Tags: sikuli

Sikuli

I need to check if a specific region that exists images I want to click, and images will show up randomly, I write the code to check that, however it takes over 10 seconds to check the region, is there anyway I can shorten the time.

```
Settings.MinSimilarity = 0.95
Reg = Region(582,404,214,187)
img = capture(Reg)
search = True
Settings.MoveMouseDelay = 0
while search :
    if  Reg.exists("12.png") or Reg.exists("13.png") or Reg.exists("14.png")or Reg.exists("15.png")or Reg.exists("28.png"):
        click(Reg.getLastMatch())
        search = False
```

Comment: Have a look here: http://eugenesautomation.blogspot.com.au/2015/01/optimizing-pattern-matching-using-sikuli_21.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `0` parameter to the `exists()` call.

So instead of

```
if  Reg.exists("12.png") or Reg.exists("13.png") or Reg.exists("14.png")or Reg.exists("15.png")or Reg.exists("28.png"):
```

You would have:

```
if  Reg.exists("12.png",0) or Reg.exists("13.png",0) or Reg.exists("14.png",0)or Reg.exists("15.png",0)or Reg.exists("28.png",0):
```

According to [this](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/189606), the zero parameter means that

> 0 as the second parameter to exists forces, that only one search is executed and the result returned immediately. It does not wait the standard 3 seconds, so it is very responsive.

The smaller the region, the faster this will be.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Reg.setAutoWaitTimeout(0.5)
```

This reduce time for detection from 3 secs to 0.5 secs or the value you like.